# How should i write the command in .cy-gitlab.yml?

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci, pulumi

I want to write expression into a file

```
 - '{ "FRONTEND_URL":"http://$(pulumi stack output frontendUrl)" } >> cypress.env.json'
```

Now I get the error message

```
Outputs:
    backendUrl : "backend-loadbalance-6ac6577-668084404.eu-north-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
   frontendUrl: "frontend-loadbalance-58e3866-1753808242.eu-north-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
 Resources:
    60 unchanged
 Duration: 12s  
$ BACKEND_URL=http://$(pulumi stack output backendUrl)/helloworld >> test.env
$ { "FRONTEND_URL":"http://$(pulumi stack output frontendUrl)" } >> cypress.env.json
/bin/bash: eval: line 148: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

How do I write this command ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, first your bash syntax is off. I'm not sure you really wanted to use `{}` literally in bash there. It seems like you meant for that to be part of the JSON object, not part of the bash script exactly.

But to do what you ultimately want to do, you could use `jq` or `jo` to make/edit your JSON file. This will be helpful especially if your variables could contain characters that need to be escaped in JSON.

Assuming you have an existing `cypress.env.json` you want to modify to include your two new variables using `jq`:

```yaml
script: |
 # install jq if needed!
 FRONTEND_URL="$(pulumi stack output frontendUrl)"
 BACKEND_URL="$(pulimi stack output backendUrl)"
 cat cypress.env.json | \
   jq --arg FRONTEND_URL "$FRONTEND_URL" \
      --arg BACKEND_URL "$BACKEND_URL" \
      '.FRONTEND_URL = $FRONTEND_URL | .BACKEND_URL = $BACKEND_URL' > new.json
 cp new.json cypress.env.json
```

As a minimal example:

```sh
$ cat cypress.env.json  # the existing file
{"FOO": "bar"}
$ FRONTEND_URL="foobar.frontend"
$ BACKEND_URL="foobar.backend"
$ cat cypress.env.json | \
   jq --arg FRONTEND_URL "$FRONTEND_URL" \
      --arg BACKEND_URL "$BACKEND_URL" \
      '.FRONTEND_URL = $FRONTEND_URL | .BACKEND_URL = $BACKEND_URL' > new.json
$ cat new.json # new file created with jq
{
  "FOO": "bar",
  "FRONTEND_URL": "foobar.frontend",
  "BACKEND_URL": "foobar.backend"
}
```